# PHP executar comando sudo com shell_exec()

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, shell-script

Estou com o seguinte problema, Estou a tempo tentando rodar um aquivo `sh` com o php usando `shell_exec` por exemplo:

```
echo shell_exec("./example etc etc");
```

O meu problema é que ele não executa, será algum problema de permissão?
detalhe que quando digito: `php x.php` ele retorna certinho (só testei com o usuário root)

Comment: Sem você colocar o que aparece no log de erros, fica difícil saber. Seria bom [edit] e acrescentar esta informação relevante.

Comment: Alguns comandos são desabilitados por padrão.  Se você atualizar a pergunta usando o comando real, e não um exemplo, vai ser mais fácil pra obter ajuda.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se você quiser executar o comando através da url do arquivo, exemplo http://exemplo.com/teste.php e nesse teste.php tem seu shell_exec, você precisa certificar-se que o [Apache](https://www.apache.org/) tem permissão para executar esse comando.

Para dar a permissão ao Apache basta saber o usuário, isso vai depender da distribuição do Linux que esteja utilizando. Se você estiver utilizando [CentOS](https://www.centos.org/) será Apache mesmo, caso esteja utilizando [Ubuntu](https://www.ubuntu.com/) será **www-data**.

Após saber disso verifique qual o caminho do arquivo onde estão os arquivos que você quer executar a permissão *sudo* pelo Apache, ai você edita o *sudoers*

```
vim /etc/sudoers
```

e adicione a seguinte linha.

```
apache          ALL=(root)  NOPASSWD: /caminho/da/sua/pasta
```

ou

```
www-data        ALL=(root)  NOPASSWD: /caminho/da/sua/pasta
```

Basicamente você estará dizendo ao servidor que seu Apache tem permissão para executar os arquivos dessa pasta como **root**.

Comment: Obrigado Cara, Funcionou perfeitamente!