# Existe usuário root no PHP?

Tags: php, linux

A função `chroot()` precisa do super usuário para funcionar, existe um função que faça login como root?

Comment: [PHP executar comando sudo com shell_exec()](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/164869/70)

Comment: Por curiosidade, qual a necessidade de permitir o PHP acessar diretamente algo no nível root? Quero dizer se quer usar para scripts PHP no terminal bastaria usar o `sudo` (ou `su`) o que resolveria, agora rodar em ambiente web não vejo necessidade real.

Comment: Meu caro amigo, há necessidade, pós como eu já havia dito. A FUNÇÃO REQUER NIVEL DE ROOT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso é configuração de máquina, inclua seu usuário do Apache (www-data) no sudoers. No terminal, faça:

```
# visudo 
# vim /etc/sudoers
```

Adicione no final do arquivo:

```
www-data ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

Mas cuidado com isso. Você estará deixando o Apache fazer o que quiser. Existem formas de você especificar o que o usuário pode fazer como root, o que é ideal para o seu caso.

Comment: Ok, você poderia me dar uma ajuda com isso? É que sou leigo e tals kkk

Comment: Entra como root no terminal e executa esses comandos que coloquei. No arquivo, abaixo de onde tem "User privileges specification" adiciona a linha mencionada.

Comment: Para colocar comandos específicos, você pode usar www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: <pathdocomando>.

Comment: Reparei que essa função só funciona no terminal. Por isso que não está funcionando